# How to check browser back button is clicked when child window is opened?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have to fix one issue in our application that, If child window is opened and user clicks on Browser back button i need to redirect to page asking username and password.
 we have 400 aspx pages so just i need to modify in master page. I have code like below

```
function initPage(){
    checkback();
}
```

This function is written in external javascript file and used in Master Page.
checkback function contains code like below

```
if (document.forms[0].cprotection.value=='1')   
{

   document.forms[0].pagecode.value=0;     
   document.forms[0].act.value='backpressed';
   document.forms[0].submit()
}
```

The above code is working fine for parent window but not if i open child window.
backpressed is keyword am using to check in class file to redirect to page asking username and password. Please help me out in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable to the session when the child window is loaded and if the user clicks back you would check the session to see if the variable that the child window added to session is nothing inside whichever pages load function and if it is then load normally, if its not redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thanks for reply, We are using cookieless session so in our application we are not using Session variable. In Javascript can i do any modifications regarding this or to keep track of id as per your solution. Also can i get browser event in codefile

Comment: @Rakesh B: That complicates things. Only using javascript for this seems like it would be borderline cross site scripting which most clients have blocked by default because of its hacking vulnerability. The issue is that any changes you make using javascript will be discarded when the user clicks the back button since you will basically be reloading the page from scratch. So without involving some sort of server side code I'm not sure how to handle this scenario. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i will speak with my panels, actually we have 480 aspx pages including child window so we have to do in javascript was the requirement, anyway i will see to it.